# How can I remove small parallel line in image?

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, graphics, computer-vision

I have black and white image after binarization. After that I have image like below:

[image: http://ifotos.pl/zobacz/ipng_xhnxhrh.png/]

How can I remove the small lines parallel to the long curves using OpenCV?. I can remove them by removing all small objects, but I want to remove only the small parallel
lines.

Comment: Can you post the image BEFORE binarization? By binarizing it you lose information.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a Canny artifact (or some kind of ringing artifact) to me. There are several ways to remove them.

An empiric but not too computing intensive method would be to locate all small features, and superimpose them with the same image shifted by [+/-]X, [+/-]Y. If the feature is completely coincident with the shifted image, i.e., all pixels in the white feature are also white in the shifted image, then you are *probably* looking at an artifact.

To evaluate "smallness" of feature, you can use a basic floodfill. This method is cheap because you can simulate shifting with pointers, without really allocating four shifted images. It is prone to false positives wherever you really have small parallel lines, and to false negatives if the artifacts are very large.

Another method would be to posterize twice the original image with different thresholds. While the "real" lines will stay together, the ringing artifacts will have a different strength. At that point you evaluate the image difference, and consider "artifact" all features that are *farther* than a given threshold from the image track. This is a bit more computation intensive, yields better results, but depends on what you have for an original image, i.e. what is your workflow.

It is possible that reevaluating the workflow (altering the edge detection phase) could avoid the creation of the artifacts altogether.

Answer (score 2):

use [cvBlobslib library](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/cvBlobsLib) to detect the white patches as blobs...the cvBlobslib library gives functions by which you can find out different features of the blobs like area , and ellipticity...so if you want only the smaller patches parallel to the long curve...then ..

1. Get the long curve on the basis of area covered by the blob or the preimeter i.e. contour length of the blob...
2. Get the ellipticity or the orientation of the major axis of the long curve after fitting an ellipse(cvBlobslib library will do that for you..!!)...
3. Filter all those blobs which are less than a threshold in terms of area or contour and **have the same orientation as the long curve**....

hope this might work..

Answer (score 1):

If you know the orientation of your line in advance, you can do a morphological closing with a custom structuring element adapted to your needs.

See morphomat on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology)

See opencv [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?#void%20morphologyEx%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20int%20op,%20InputArray%20kernel,%20Point%20anchor,%20int%20iterations,%20int%20borderType,%20const%20Scalar&%20borderValue%29)

Comment: Yes I can use morphology but then it change all object but I want to do it only with these parallel!!!

Comment: restrain the morphological operations to a ROI close to the main diagonal

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps similar to what the others said, but in simpler words: since the small lines seem to have roughly half the thickness of the long ones, if you don't really care about preserving the long lines the way they are, you could apply several times a simple algorithm that "makes the lines thinner", until the small ones disappear. What you need to do is scan the image pixel by pixel and when you detect a white pixel above or below or to the left or to the right of a black pixel, you store its coordinates in a vector. After you traverse the entire image, you make all the pixels specified by the coordinates in the vector black. You could define some threshold empirically for the number of iterations of this algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Here are steps exploiting the fact that parallel lines are increasing edge density.

1) Apply `adaptive Threshold` on gray image to get many edges.

2) `Erode` 3x3 (or experiment but small) Morphological Operation.

3) Take `Logical Not` to get edge density.

4) Apply `Dilate` of like 3x3 or 5x5. It will dilate edges to merge and make a region.

5) Now `Erode` 7x7 (or experiment for higher then last dilate) Morphological Operation. It will remove most of the non-required region, long lines and small stray areas.

Output is is MASK for removal region. You can apply contour detection on original image and remove contour-object for matching position in mask high precision removal.
OR if you don't need high-precision result simply `And` with mask's `NOT`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not doing something like:

1. Find the long curves (using `findContours` and filter by size).
2. Find the small curves
3. For each long curve, calculate the minimal distance between each point of every small curve and the long curve.
4. Calculate the mean and the standard deviation of these minimal distances.
5. Reject small curves for which either the mean minimal distance to the long curve is too large, or small curves for which the standard deviation of the minimal distances is large.

The result will probably be better (and faster) is you skeletonize the image first.

Good luck with it,